# Calculate distance based on framerate

Tags: calculus

I am making a JavaScript game and I want to calculate the amount of pixels to move something depending on the fps(frames per second). I already have a function to calculate the fps, what i want is to calculate the amount of pixels to move something based on the fps. So if my fps is 60 I want pixels to move to be 30, and if my fps is 30 i want pixels too move to be 60 and so on. I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: They're inversely proportional. Thus, if $p$ is the number of pixels to be moved, then $(p)(\text{fps})$ is constant, equal to $k$ say. Thus, if you have one example, that allows you to find $k$, hence you get
$$p = \frac{k}{\text{fps}}$$

Comment: Thank you, you have definitely put me on the right track :)